# What is equivalent for Delphi ORD, SHL and SHR functions SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I have 2 Delphi functions that I need to move to SQL Server but I am not sure about the equivalent for ORD, SHL and SHR functions. Can somebody perhaps help on how these Delphi functions would look like in SQL?

```
function QX_Encrypt(s:String) : String;
var 
    sTempString : string;
    iIndex , i: integer;
begin
    sTempString  := s ;
    for iIndex := 1 to length(sTempString) do
    begin
        i := ord(sTempString[iIndex]);
        i:= i shl 1;
        sTempString[iIndex] := char(i) ;
    end;
    result := stempstring;
end;

function QX_Decrypt(s:String) : String;
var 
    sTempString : string;
    iIndex , i : integer;
begin
    sTempString  := s ;
    for iIndex := 1 to length(sTempString) do
    begin
        i := ord(sTempString[iIndex]);
        i:= i shr 1;
        sTempString[iIndex] := char(i) ;
    end;
    result := sTempString;
end;
```

Comment: I know nothing of Delphi, but a quick [google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&channel=crow&q=Delphi+Ord+SQL+Server) led me to see that `Ord` and `ASCII` (or `UNICODE` if you're working with an `nvarchar`) appear to be equivalents. And the first result from [Delphi SHL SQL Server](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&channel=crow&q=Delphi+SHL+SQL+Server) looks very promising.

Comment: ORD = ASCII; shl 1 = * 2 (multiply by 2); shr 1 = / 2 (divide by 2)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the guidance. Here is a snippet that did what I wanted.

```
DECLARE 
    @cnt INT = 1,
    @Password nvarchar(20) = 'P@ssword1',
    @NewPassword nvarchar(20)
WHILE @cnt < LEN(@Password) + 1
BEGIN
    SELECT @NewPassword = CONCAT(@NewPassword, CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Password, @cnt, 1)) * 2))
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
SELECT @NewPassword
```